# schengen visa taking to much processing time

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas

I had a conference in Spain Barcelona, I applied for a visa at 17/01/2020

they said it'll take 15 days and till today 15/02/2020 yet no answer, can anybody advice me what to do?

Comment: The best advice for people who might get in your circumstances is 'do not commit to travel till you have your visa, and apply well in advance' which is no use to you now. I do not know whether you can do anything. (I am no visa specialist.)

Comment: I think it is time for a backup plan. For example, if you are presenting at the conference, try to make arrangements to do so remotely.

Answer (score 2):

Do not assume that the *generel rule* **always** applies.

The **complete** text states that it *can* take longer, depending on the situation.

Since no one here knows about your specific situation (such as first time applicant etc.), no one can give any other realistic answer than:

- you must wait

---

> **Processing of a visa application**
> As a general rule, a decision is taken by the Consulate within 15 days.
>
> This period may, in individual cases, be extended up to 30 days and, exceptionally, 60 days, if a more detailed examination of your application and/or additional documents are required.

---

**Sources**:

- [European Commission - Processing of a visa application](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/visa_application_en)